# Controlled input changing on setState()

Tags: reactjs

I have this constructor in React component:

```
constructor() {

        super();

        this.state = {
            info: {
                title: '',
                description: '',
                height: ''
            }
        }

...
```

And a form with inputs controlled by the state:

```
    <form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
      <label>Title:</label>
      <input type="text" name="title" value={this.state.info.title} onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)} />
      <label>Description:</label>
      <input type="text" name="description" value={this.state.info.description} onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)} />
...
```

When I type anything on the form, I guess there's something wrong with my handler, as I get the warning "*Warning: A component is changing a controlled input of type text to be uncontrolled. Input elements should not switch from controlled to uncontrolled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.*"

Checking console, it seems state is updating each property value that is being typed, and removing other properties, while it should remain all of them and only update the changed ones.

Here's my handler:

```
handleChange(event) {
        let { name, value } = event.target;
        this.setState({
            info: {
                [name]: value
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the one you are using is updating only one props and the others being stripped that causes React shows warning. you can use spreading to keep the others

```
handleChange(event) {
    let { name, value } = event.target;
    this.setState({
        info: {
            ...this.state.info,
            [name]: value
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU. I'll tick in some minutes.

Comment: you may want to use the function version of set state in this case, so you don't end up with stale values...

Answer (score 1):

There's usually 2 cases which cause such warnings to manifest in my experience.

1. The initial value of the property in state is undefined and not being changed when updated
2. The initial value is '' and being changed to null

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
handleChange(event) {
        let { name, value } = event.target;
        this.setState(({info}) =>({
            info: {
                [name]: value
            }
        }));
    }
```

Breaking down the function call:

- First you have `this.setState(updaterFunction)`. `updaterFunction` gets called by `setState` with the previous state as the argument, and that function is expected to return an object with the keys of the state to update (it gets merged shallowly with the previous state).
- Because `setState` is only a *shallow* merge (no matter if you pass it an object or a function), if you have an object at like `this.state.foo.bar` and you update the state with an object like `{foo: {bar: 'qux'} }`, the old `foo` will not get merged with the new foo, it will instead get replaced. So your updater function needs to do the deeper merging manually.
- The updaterFunction looks like this `({info})=>({…})`. We pull `info` out of the previous state, and we return an object, using `info` to manually do the deeper merging.

The benefit of passing a function to `setState` (instead of just an object) is that if you use the state passed to the function instead of `this.state`, you will avoid some potential bugs when multiple `setState` calls get batched together....

Comment: Thank you Garret, also great alternative